# Query to find exact row from Table1 which are not available in Table2

Tags: sql

Table1

| MarketID | Employee ID |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 501 |
| 102 | 502 |
| 103 | 503 |
| 104 | 504 |
| 105 | 505 |

Table2

| MarketID | Employee ID |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 501 |
| 102 | 502 |
| 103 | 504 |
| 106 | 505 |
| 107 | 507 |

Expected Output:

| MarketID | Employee ID |
| --- | --- |
| 103 | 503 |
| 104 | 504 |
| 105 | 505 |

I want to prepare a sql query to find exact full row data from table1 which are not available in Table2.

Comment: Please, show your current attempt. Without your own work you will not learn anything

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Check my answer for your question

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase this using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT MarketID, EmployeeID
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.MarketID = t1.MarketID AND
                        t2.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **EXCEPT** for this use case like below.

```
SELECT MarketID, EmployeeID
FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT MarketID, EmployeeID
FROM Table2;
```

If you interested to look on other alternatives, Please visit this Stackoverflow post where I have covered 10 other alternatives for the same - [An alternative for "NOT IN" in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614196/an-alternative-for-not-in-in-sql-server/59789254#59789254)